# Сокращение количества дубликатов в таблице

Tags: sql

Есть таблицы с моделями и марками ТС, согласно `VEHICLE_MODELS`, `VEHICLE_MARKS`. Они используются в таблице `POLICIES`.
Человек, который заполняет `POLICIES`, забивают модель и марку, если их нет в БД, или вытягивает с БД существующую.
Суть проблемы в том, что пользователи всё создают и создают марки и модели. Так у нас появилось много дубликатов.
К примеру, приведу возможные дубликаты ТС **MERCEDES-BENZ E300**. Поля `mark` и `model` не повторяются. Все дубликаты различаются между собой как минимум пробелом:

```
+-----------------+---------+
|       mark      |  model  |
+-----------------+---------+
| MERSEDES-BENZ   |  E300   |
+-----------------+---------+
| MERCEDES-BENZ   |  E300   |
+-----------------+---------+
| MERCEDES - BENZ |  E300   |
+-----------------+---------+
| MERCEDES-BENZ   | E 300   |
+-----------------+---------+
| MERS            | E300    |
+-----------------+---------+
| MERS-BENZ       | E300    |
+-----------------+---------+
| MERSEDES-BNEZ   | E 300   |
+-----------------+---------+
```

Как можно удалить все дубликаты или хоть частично сократить их число?

Comment: ООО!!!! Даааа!!!! "Эти юзеры" - мягко Вы как-то... Я в таких случаях создаю новую колонку в таблице. Туда переношу собранные вместе значения полей `CONCAT()`, убираю все, кроме букв и цифр, а потом уже по этому полю ищу дубликаты и вытираю их.... В Вашем случае это сильно поможет :)

Comment: посмотрите [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/25990/179270), ну и от себя, после удаления дубликатов если есть возможность измените структуру бд(создайте индекс) дабы избежать появления дубликатов.

Comment: @cyadvert, пытался скрыть эмоций и задать объективный вопрос). Можете по-подробней рассказать?

Comment: @Saidolim дает вполне приемлемый ответ. Только я бы в колонку `mark` в его случае внес объединенными оба поля...

Comment: а обрезать лишние пробелы перед сохранением в БД? это поможет сократить такие дубликаты как *"E300"* и *"E300 "* и *" E300"* ну и т.п.

Comment: @Bald56rus, спасибо за совет, но эти моменты уже исправляются. Сейчас важное это сократить число дубликатов в БД.

Comment: Программно можно сократить только записи 2,3 и 4, потому что они эдентичны, если все убрать. Все остальные записи потребуют человеческого вмешательства. Увы :(... "Эти юзеры"!!!!

Comment: посмотрите ссылку которую я Вам привел Выше там можно посмотреть различные способы как избавиться от дубликатов в БД, либо @Saidolim в своем ответе вам привел пример, но от всех избавиться не получиться как понять что это дубликат *MERCEDES-BENZ* и *MERS-BENZ* только Ваше непосредственное участие или же того кто наплодил этих дубликатов, что бы в следующий раз пользовались "Серым веществом"

Comment: @cyadvert никто не без греха, а не только "эти юзеры". Автор вопроса, например, считает, что _"Mercedes"_ пишется через две _"s"_. Вы - что слово _"идентичный"_ начинается с буквы _"э"_.

Comment: @Regent где я так написал?)))

Comment: @ШыназАлиш историю правок никто не отменял :) Но я в любом случае поставил плюс вопросу. К сожалению, новых идей решения проблемы силами SQL у меня нет.

Comment: Радикально решить проблему можно, только запретив пользователю вводить подобные данные. Для этого нужно создать справочную таблицу доступных моделей и выбирать оттуда.

Comment: Задача в общем случае не имеет 100% решения. Даже искусственный интеллект не сможет однозначно сопоставить такие идентичные марки как: "шоха", "девятка", "таз", "ваз", "жигуль", "лада", "копейка" и т.п.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все немного проще:

1) Обновляем записи, убирая пробелы:

```
UPDATE `test` as t1
    INNER JOIN `test` as t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
    SET 
        t1.mark = replace(t2.mark,' ',''),
        t1.model = replace(t2.model,' ','')
```

2) Убираем одинаковые записи через `distinct`(правильный delete with select):

```
DELETE FROM `test`
WHERE id NOT IN (
        SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT id FROM `test`
                GROUP by mark, model
        ) as P
    )
```

P.S.: можно еще запрос на удаление совпадений с сокращениями вроде MERS удалить, но тут нужно быть осторожнее, т.к. нужно точно знать что MERS есть сокращение MERSEDES(т.е. чтобы не удалить сокращения к иным полным наименованиям).

P.P.S.: для оптимизации лучше всего создать отдельную таблицу или поле в существующей(таблица лучше), где Вы сможете хранить сокращения и производные от настоящих наименований, таким образом Вы избежите подобных ситуаций.

Answer (score 3):

1. Используйте `DISTINCT`. Это поможет сократить идентичные данные.

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT mark, model
     FROM table_name;
   ```
2. Создаёте дополнительное поле, в котором будет храниться `MERCEDES-BENZ` в сокращённом виде, то есть без пробелов. Потом делаете группировку по этому полю:

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT min(mark), model, mark_without_space
     FROM table_name
    GROUP BY mark_without_space, model;
   ```
3. Этот вариант используется в лингвистике. В поле `mark_without_space` сохраняете `mark` без пробелов и без гласных букв.

**UPDATE:**

Для удаления:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
 WHERE ID NOT IN (
    SELECT id 
      FROM
      (SELECT DISTINCT min(id) id, mark, model
         FROM table_name) t1
    ) t2;
```

или

```
DELETE FROM table_name
 WHERE ID NOT IN (
    SELECT min(id)
      FROM table_name
  GROUP BY mark, model) t;
```

Comment: а как Вы в этом случае избавляетесь от дубликатов, в Вашем ответе Вы их убираете из выборки, в БД они остаются

Comment: @Bald56rus а в приведенном примере полностью избавиться от дубликатов не возможно. Записи `MERS` и `MERS-BENZ` выпадают.

Comment: @cyadvert да полностью никак не получится, нужно все равно вмешательство человека

Comment: @cyadvert согласен, ну хотя бы явные дубликаты можно убрать, и запретить создавать явные дубликаты типа MERCEDES-BENZ E300, т.е. создаем индекс, обрезаем лишние пробелы в начале и конце строки

Comment: В Вашем ответе: `WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT [три колонки] FROM table_name);` разве сработает? Одну колонку с тремя сравнивать?

Comment: @cyadvert согласен, спасибо, не до конца сформировал

Comment: @Saidolim у вас ошибки в обеих запроса `DELETE`.

Answer (score 2):

Коллеги уже достаточно внятно написали варианты как избавиться от таких дублей. Я же напишу про то как избавиться от появления дублей в будущем.

Есть такое понятие "классификатор" - это простая таблица содержащее ключевое поле и поле с содержимым, типа:

```
MarkId | Mark
-----------------------
  1    | Mercedes Benz
  2    | Toyota
```

Юзеру предоставляется выбор только из этого списка. Если нужно завести новую запись, то имеется отдельный "продвинутый" юзер, который и добавляет запись в эту таблицу.

Иначе вам так и придется сидеть вылавливать Mercedes, Mercedez, Мерин, Мерседес и проч. сомнительные синонимы.